# How can I put the current timestamp in a Mongoose Schema?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

As per the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html), I can do this for a date:

```
new Schema({
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
})
```

But what if I need time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like that does timestamps too!